# Clicking on a listbox means I can't click on anything else on the form

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm using a databound listbox in a C# WinForm application.

When I click on an item in the listbox nothing else on the form works, even when I click on the close button the form doesn't close. Everything works fine until I select an item.

What I have tried to do is in the listbox1_SelectedIndexChanged set the listbox1 focus to false but that didn't work.

Code sample: This is the code that assigns the listbox to the data source:

```
this.ListBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.table1BindingSource, "PrimaryKeyId", true));
this.ListBox1.DataSource = this.table1BindingSource;
this.ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.ListBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.ListBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.ListBox1.ItemHeight = 24;
this.ListBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(185, 28);
this.ListBox1.Name = "ListBox1";
this.ListBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(660, 532);
this.ListBox1.TabIndex = 7;
this.ListBox1.ValueMember = "Name";
this.ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

ListBox1 isn't referenced anywhere else. This is the initial code I was using before:

```
private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox1.Focus().Equals(false);
}
```

This is the code I am now running:

```
private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GroupBox1.Focus().Equals(true);
}
```

Then on Windows load I have: `table1TableAdapter.Fill(this.Application1DataSet.Table1);`
I've debug the windows load and the listbox1 method so I don't think it's a loop. Also the app doesn't crash so I don't think it's a loop.

Comment: I'm only putting this here 'cause I couldn't find anything on google.

Comment: Can you post a code sample? Make sure you are not doing something else when you click the item - maybe you disable everything or you get in an infinite loop on the main thread.

Comment: Unless there's somewhere else a loop could exist. There isn't a lot of code in the project in the first place.

Comment: Was there a reason for making this question CW?

Comment: I thought it was SO etiquette to mark questions as CW when you answer them yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
ListBox1.Focus().Equals(false);
```

...does not "un-focus" the list box.

If you look at the [documentation for `Focus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx), you'll see that it **focuses** the control, if it can, otherwise it returns `false`.

Tacking on `.Equals(false)` simply compares the *result* of that call to the value `false`.  In other words, it's equivalent to writing this:

```
!ListBox1.Focus()
```

Which pretty obviously does *not* remove focus from the list box, it actually **sets** focus to the list box in most cases.  You are simply making a comparison on the return value and then throwing the result of the comparison away.

As you discovered yourself, there is no method to *remove* focus from a control.  You can only set focus to some other control.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you write:

```
listBox1.ValueMember = "PrimaryKeyId";
```

Comment: I end up with an error: "Column 'PrimaryKeyId' is constrained to be unique.  Value '5' is already present." Where 5 is the value of the idea I'm going to select. But that only happens if I click two listbox items in a row.

Comment: But that is a completely different problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered this when developing an application but thank God, this worked.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What did work was setting the focus to another control on the form. But it's still a weird problem.